# My Selenium IE instance not loading for Users that are not administrators

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

I wrote an application in C# to automate logging on to a webpage.

It works perfectly whenever an Admin runs the executable. Whenever a non-admin runs the project, it's as if IEDriver.exe doesn't launch. There are no restrictions of launching IEDriver.exe from a group policy.

```
private IWebDriver _driver;

public void SetUp()
{
        InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.EnsureCleanSession = true;
        options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
        options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
        options.EnablePersistentHover = false;

        var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.LibraryExtractionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        //service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        _driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options);
}
```

when I uncomment the LibraryExtractionPath, IEDriver doesn't launch.

When I debug the code.

```
 Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

points to the correct location which is

> D:\PathToFolder\Project1\bin\Debug\

I think the problem is that the clients (as non-admin) are unable to launch IEDriver.exe

UPDATE: Internet Explorer's Protected Mode is not disabled, [which can prevent running IE Driver as a non-admin user](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver). Can I disable it using C# code and IE service options?

Comment: Where exactly does `LibraryExtractionPath` point to? What's the location of it?

Comment: Well it's suppose to point to the directory where the EXE is being launched from

Comment: "Suppose to"? Can we get the *exact* location that string is pointing to? Where does the driver live?

Comment: Where does this resolve to? Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

Comment: I don't know - I'm asking you. It's your code, not mine :) Have a look, what does Visual Studio say is the value of that string?

Comment: The driver is in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: @Arran i know that the Path.GetDirectoryName points to the correct location. How can I get it to load the IEDriver from that location

Comment: D drive? Is that local or a shared drive?

Comment: Shared Network Drive

Comment: Any suggestion about the IEDriverServer?

Comment: @Arran any suggestion for the issue? Please advise

Comment: If it's on a network drive, it's probably permissions related - check with your IT team. What's the permissions like on the folder that it lives in?

Comment: Authenticated Users have Modify permission. All users are in that Authenticated Users group

Comment: @softwareisfun Longshot, but is it possible you haven't disabled/changed the Protected Mode settings for Internet Explorer, so IE Driver can launch the browser itself for each user? https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: Protected Mode is on. Can I disable it using C# code and IE service options?

Comment: @softwareisfun That I do not know myself, since it's a C# question! But at least now you know about one issue which is blocking you. Maybe you can edit or ask a new question about this specifically?

Comment: @softwareisfun Can you also add information to your main post about which version(s) of Internet Explorer & Windows you're using? Different IE versions may require different solutions.

Comment: All the computers are running Windows 7 with IE10. There is suppose to be a group policy in place to do things like turn on protected mode, enable and set proxy servers, etc

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of the path you have supplied

> D:\PathToFolder\Project1\bin\Debug\

You are trying to run the driver from where it hase been compiled by Visual Studio. There are a couple of reasons why this may not work.

When you setup and compiled the code in visual studio it would have created the debug folder ect and used the permissions of the current user. This means that that user and Admins may be able to access it but no body else. Or if this was done as an Admin it may only be accessible to admins.

Quiet often Visual Studio and other IDEs will also have a different working directory and compile the exe into different directories depending on what build options you have selected. For example release versus debug. What this means is that dll's ect used by the exe are not in the same diretory as the exe. When you run inside visual studio this isn't a problem as it set the correct working directory and sorts it all out for you. In your case it is probably not quiet that simple if this is part of the problem. What it might mean is that any requisite dll's ect might be installed and in the path for the Admin but not for normal users.

What this breaks down to is this is likely a path or permissions issue. I would suggest using something like Dependency walker to see what the  of the exe are: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and ensuring that all users can access them.

If you do this as a user that the program is not working for dependency walker will show you what dependencies are not being found.